# Microsoft Visio 2010 Premium missing "Software & Database" templates

Tags: microsoft-visio, templates, microsoft-visio-2010, diagrams

In Microsoft Visio 2007, there was a "Software & Database" template to be able to draw ER diagrams.  In Visio 2010, this template is missing.  Does anyone know if this template (and others missing) can be downloaded and installed in Visio 2010?  Can you explain how this can be done?

## EDIT:

Based on the answers posted and comments, I've done the following.

The templates might have been installed incorrectly here, which conflicts with one of the comments posted about the path of these templates.  Notice two "Office14" folders:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Office14\Visio Content\1033
```

I was able to get *some* of the templates to show up (File > New) by doing the following:

1. Microsoft Visio
2. File
3. Options
4. Advanced
5. File Locations (button at very bottom)
6. then specify the path above for the “Templates” field.

You may have to restart Visio.

This however does NOT allow access to DBMODL_U.VST (Database Modeling template), probably because the DBMODL_U.VSS file is missing.

I've also tried moving the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Office14\Visio Content` folder into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14`, but that did not do anything, even after a Windows restart.

Comment: The latest version of Visio Pro for Office 365 has Reverse Engineering capabilities. I found this article to be very helpful: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-fb034862-acfc-45bc-88b2-f33d1e1f8614

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the Software and Database option then you don't have Visio Professional. They still exist in Visio 2010 Professional and Premium.

Comment: I'm also confirming from this list that they *should* exist in Premium.  http://www.visguy.com/2010/06/15/visualization-of-visio-2010-templates-by-edition/

Answer (score 1):

It's still there - isn't it this one?

[image: Database Model Diagram]

Comment: Yes, it's missing in my install for some reason.

Comment: I think the template file is DBMODL_U.VST or DBMODL_M.VST (metric). Try searching for those to see if they're present. Mine are under %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office14\Visio Content

Comment: That last folder does not exist in my install.

Comment: Exists in mine...

Comment: See EDIT posted today

Answer (score 0):

Version: Visio 2016 Standard

I was able to use the 'Shapes for Crows Foot Database Notation' after finding and double clicking the following Visio Template:

English Crow Template:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\Visio Content\1033\DBCROW_M.VSTX

German Crow Template:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\Visio Content\1031\DBCROW_M.VSTX